# how to change time format hh:mm in rdlc report expression

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services, rdlc

How to change time format `hh:mm` (military time format) in RDLC report expression if my dataset field data type is (string, time or TimeSpan).

I am using this format `=FORMAT(First(Fields!Time.Value, "dataset"),"hh\.mm")` but it is not working.

Please let me know how to solve this issue because I do not want to modify Stored Procedures.

Your solution can save my time.

Comment: What does the field currently have? If it's a date stored as CHAR, you can just convert it to work a s a date with CDATE(Fields!Time.Value).

Answer (score 0):

Go to textbox properties and set format value to "HH:mm"

you can change it from Text Box Properties dialog:
[image]